# Find fourth derivative of function

Tags: functions, derivatives

The function is $\displaystyle{\frac{3x^4}{1-x}}$ and I am trying to find $\displaystyle{\frac{d^4}{dx^4}}$. However, I want to find the solution without using the quotient rule $4$ times in a row. I am unsure of the best alternate method. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use long division (or synthetic division) [to see that](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3x%5E4+%2F+%281+-+x%29)

$$\frac{3x^4}{1 - x} = -3x^3 - 3x^2 - 3x - 3 - \frac{3}{x - 1}$$

Once you've done this, the first four terms will vanish upon differentiating $4$ times, and the last term is fairly easy to study, since it can be written as $-3 (x - 1)^{-1}$; now use the power rule and the chain rule a few times.